# How to implement user configurable web pages in a ASP.Net/AJAX web app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, configurable

I need some advice to save me re-inventing the wheel.

Our windows app is being redesigned as a web app [ASP.Net/AJAX dot Net 3.5 - SQL Server 2005 DB] and we are at the begining of the process.

One of the requirements is that the customer should have some control over the page layout .i.e. type of controls, position of controls and what data the controls are bound to etc. for example to be able to add a textbox/dropdown and bind it to the appropiate field in the database. Transforms would be used to merge the data and the layout.

Our initial plan is to drive this from 4-5 SQL Server tables defining the screens,  controls, layout etc and using transforms to build the page at runtime with caching where appropiate.

Is there an alternative way to do this or has anyone expierence with the above method and its advantages and/or limitations.

Thanks in advance,
Liam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a portal -have you looked into [using ASP.NET WebParts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0s9t4ck.aspx)?

Comment: Just had a look and it seems like a runner. 

We can design the solution in a standard way then use web parts to enable the user configuration rather than compromising the design and the maintainability from the start to provide configuration

Appreciate the speedy, helpful and accurate response.
Many thanks -Liam